# Return parameter can't be accepted in c++ template

Tags: c++, templates

I am writing a template for binary tree and don't understand why I can't return Node* from one of my functions in that template.

Code:

```
template<class T>
class Binary_Tree{
private:
    struct Node{
        T* data;
        Node *left,*right;
        Node(T* dat, Node* l, Node* r) : data(dat),left(l=0),right(r=0) {} 
    }*root;
public:
    Binary_Tree() : root(0) {}
    Node* find(T* dat);
....
};


template<class T>
Node* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node* current){
    if (*current->data == *dat){
        return current;
    }else if(*current->data < *dat && current->left == 0){
        return current;
    }else if(*current->data > *dat && current->right == 0){
        return current;
    }else if (*current->data < *dat){
        find(dat,current->left);
    }else if(*current->data > *dat){
        find(dat,current->right);
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
}
```

Any thoughts?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not 100% certain, but I think you can't really go ACROSS templates like that. Create a class that uses the same template.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By definition, your node is private, so why would you want to return in a public method a private type ?
Moreover, sometime, compiler have hard time with templates, sometime, you need to let them know if a specific label is a variable or a type. You can use *typename* key word for that.

Additionally, you can have your node class outside of the Binary_Tree (checked, it does compile):

```
 template<class T>
 class Node {
    T* data;
    Node<T> *left,*right;
    Node<T> (T* dat, Node<T> * l, Node<T> * r) : data(dat),left(l=0),right(r=0) {}
 };

 template<class T>
 class Binary_Tree{
 private:
    Node<T> *root;
 public:
    Binary_Tree() : root(0) {}
    Node<T>* find(T* dat,Node<T> *); // changed prototype
 };


 template<class T>
 Node<T>* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node<T>* current){
     if (*current->data == *dat){
         return current;
     }else if(*current->data < *dat && current->left == 0){
         return current;
     }else if(*current->data > *dat && current->right == 0){
         return current;
     }else if (*current->data < *dat){
         return find(dat,current->left); // add missing return
     }else if(*current->data > *dat){
         return find(dat,current->right); // add missing return
     }else{
         return 0;
     }
 }
```

Comment: I've defined typedef in the public part of the body (typedef Node* node;), after seeing your comment, but still the same error: Error 1 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*'

Comment: I've taken it out, had to append <T> to the end of every Node though. It works, thanks for that. But still, why can't I use Node* as return parameter, even if I fully qualify it with Binary_Tree<T>::Node*?

Comment: Embedding private class into templates is too smart for me, I can't help you on this. Usually, if it doesn't work, it's too complex ;-) In your original example, your class is private, so unknown outside of your binary_tree class.

Comment: Okay, I agree on that note :)

Answer (score 5):

Fully qualify the return type to your find function:

```
Binary_Tree<T>::Node* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node* current){ ...
```

Comment: This, plus `struct Node` should be in the public part in order to be able to use the returned pointer.

Comment: You might also need a `typename` in front, to say that Node is a type for all T's.

Comment: hmm, fully qualifying looked very valid, until I tried but end up with the same error as well as this one: Warning 1 warning C4346: 'Linked_List<T>::Node' : dependent name is not a type
Error 2 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'Linked_List<T>::find'

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you've missed two `return`:s in the `if .. else if ..` block in `find`.

**EDIT:**

The code following code is the problem:

```
template<class T>
Node* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node* current){
  if (...) {
    ..
  } else if (*current->data < *dat){
    find(dat,current->left);
  }else if(*current->data > *dat){
    find(dat,current->right);
```

Here, you simply end the function with a call to `find`. You *have* to include the `return` statement, as in:

```
template<class T>
Node* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node* current){
  if (...) {
    ..
  } else if (*current->data < *dat){
    return find(dat,current->left);
  }else if(*current->data > *dat){
    return find(dat,current->right);
```

The C language is not like *lisp* and *ruby*, where the last line of a block is the implicit value of that block.

The fact that this is a *recursive* call does not make the call special in any way, it the end it's just a plain call, and if you plan to return the value of the call you have to return it explicitly.

Comment: I do recursion there and hope that something else comes up, but I agree that there should be a default return at the end, just to be safe...

Comment: You have a very valid point there. Thanks for pointing me that way.

Answer (score 0):

Basically, when you write this:

```
template<class T> Node* Binary_Tree<T>::find(T* dat, Node* current){ 
...
```

how is it supposed to know which `Node*` you are talking about?  You have to explicitly tell it.

But there's another, deeper issue.  That is, you have a public functions returning a pointer to a type that is only known internally (privately) to the class.  What is the caller of `find()` going to do with the `Node` that comes out.  Well by your design, the only that they can do it pass it back into one of the classes public members.  More concretely, if you expect the called of the `find()` function to do something like

```
p = tree.Find( /* some arguments */);
```

then do something with `p->left`.  Well this shouldn't compile.

A possible solution:

- Move the definition of the struct called `Node` out of the class and into the global scope.  (Actually, better yet, put it in a namespace, because `Node` is such a common name.)

Comment: I decided to hide Node as internal structure for user not to worry about. And that find() function is used only by that template's class internal functions.

Comment: That's my point.  If it's internal, then why return a pointer to one in a public member function?